# Laravel livewire - any way to get live data from database?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, real-time, real-time-data

I have a project for food ordering and deliverying. Basically this is a concept of project:

- User order a food in some restaurant
- That order of that restaurant is showing specifically to the manager of that restaurant
- Manager is getting SMS notification about new order
- He needs to refresh his dashboard to see new order

The point is in the last step **Manager needs to refresh his dashboard to see new order**.
I'm using livewire and Laravel 7 framework, is there any way for the manager to get new orders in realtime?

I know for livewire `polling` but I don't want to use that because it can cause server problems in large quantities of using it. Is there any other way? Something like `mount() function` or `emit` ?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used this feature but it seems you need [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#introduction)

> In many modern web applications, WebSockets are used to implement realtime, live-updating user interfaces. When some data is updated on the server, a message is typically sent over a WebSocket connection to be handled by the client. WebSockets provide a more efficient alternative to continually polling your application's server for data changes that should be reflected in your UI.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say. The options are either maintaining an open connection or the client polling the server.

Comment: Could I setup ```pusher``` for laravel easy on my project?